# Python Set Birthday

Tags: python, function, set

So I am trying to make a program that creates the probability of a bunch of people in a room to have the same birthday... I can't figure out how to create the function. Here is what I have so far

```
def birthday():
    mySet = set()
    x = 1
    for item in mySet:
        if item in mySet:
            return x
        else:
            mySet().append() # don't know what to do here.
```

Edit:

Alright so what I am trying to accomplish is to make a function using a set that stores birthdays using numbers 1 through 365...For example, if you randomly pick a room with 30 people in it, they may not have the same birthday. Although, if you have twins in the same room, you only need 2 people
in the room to have the same birthday. So eventually I want a parameter that tests this function several times and averages it all up. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to make this. I want x to be a counter of how many people are in the room and when there is a match the loop stops and it stops. I also don't know what to append to.

Comment: You're calculating the probability by trying all combinations until you find something you've already got - is that right?

Comment: First of all you need to clarify what you want to do better. Second of all every item IS in mySet, that's how you set up the for loop. Match what ?? there is nothing in your set. Try psudo coding what you want to do first. that code makes no sense sorry.

Comment: Yes Jon that is right

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're trying to simulate this rather than using the closed form solution to this problem? There's a pretty decent approximation that's fast and easy to code:

```
import math
def closed_form_approx_birthday_collision_probability(num_people):
    return 1 - math.exp(-num_people * (num_people - 1) / (2 * 365.0))
```

You could also implement an very good "exact" solution (in quotes because some fidelity is lost when converting to float):

```
import operator
import functools
import fractions
def slow_fac(n):
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, range(2, n+1), 1)

def closed_form_exact_birthday_collision_probability(num_people):
    p_no_collision = fractions.Fraction(slow_fac(365), 365 ** num_people * slow_fac(365 - num_people))
    return float(1 - p_no_collision)
```

To do a simulation, you'd do something like this. I'm using a list rather than a set because the number of possibilities is small and this avoids some extra work that using a set would do:

```
import random
def birthday_collision_simulate_once(num_people):
    s = [False] * 365
    for _ in range(num_people):
        birthday = random.randint(0, 364)
        if s[birthday]:
            return True
        else:
            s[birthday] = True
    return False

def birthday_collision_simulation(num_people, runs):
    collisions = 0
    for _ in range(runs):
        if birthday_collision_simulate_once(num_people):
            collisions += 1
    return collisions / float(runs)
```

The numbers I get from the simulation and the closed form solution look similar to the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

```
>>> closed_form_approx_birthday_collision_probability(20)
0.40580512747932584
>>> closed_form_exact_birthday_collision_probability(20)
0.41143838358058
>>> birthday_collision_simulation(20, 100000)
0.41108
```

Of course the simulation with that many runs is closer to the actual 41.1%, it's much slower to calculate. I'd choose one of the closed form solutions, depending on how accurate it needs to be.